# How to test an activesheet

Tags: vba, excel

Here is my code

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)

Set Sh = ActiveSheet
If ActiveSheet.Name = "Entrada" Then
    Application.Calculation = xlManual
Else
    Application.Calculation = x1automatic
End If
End Sub
```

but all the sheets is going to manual calculation, whats the error?

thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a thought on your *Sh* variable assignment. When *Sh* is passed into the `Workbook_SheetActivate` event macro, it *is* the worksheet being activated. You do not need to set it to the active sheet. The following will always report the name of the worksheet being newly activated to the Immediate window (including newly created worksheets).

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
    Debug.Print Sh.Name
End Sub
```

So your conditional statement could be tightened up to something like,

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
    If Sh.Name = "Entrada" Then
        ' do something here
    Else
        ' do something else here
     End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You are attempting to change the calculation at application level. I'm guessing you want to use

```
ActiveSheet.EnableCalculation = True ' or False
```

Answer (score 0):

The values you set to Calculation should be: `xlCalculationManual`and `xlCalculationAutomatic`, not `xlManual` and `x1automatic`

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/office/ff835845(v=office.15).aspx) and this site http://www.cpearson.com/excel/optimize.htm